# How to add a string[] array into a record<string,boolean> format using typescript?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a string array and I want to keep those value and create a new array Record

for each value in userValue.

**Example**

```
 userValue: string[] = ["1111","2222","3333","4444"];


  selectedOptions: Record<string, boolean> = {
    //how to add userValue array into here?
    1111: true, //hardcoded
    2222: true, //hardcoded
    3333: true, //hardcoded
    4444: true //hardcoded
  };
```

Comment: Use Javascript's map() function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// Create the array of strings
let userValue: string[] = ["1111","2222","3333","4444"];

// Create empty Record
let selectedOptions: Record<string, boolean> = {} as Record<string, boolean>;

// Add the array values into the Record
userValue.forEach(val => {
   selectedOptions[val] = true;
});
```